# How to mutate new variable by different rule?

Tags: r, tidyverse, mutate

Suppose I have a data frame df

`df <- tribble( ~x, ~y, 1,   'x > 3', 5,   'x > 2', 10,   'x > 1' )`

I want to create a new variable z by the condition in y, say

```
df %>% mutate(z = if_else(condition, 1, 0))
```

here the condition is in column y.

Can I create the new variable in tidy way?

Comment: As this is a combined question with duplicates as indicated by @tmfmnk I provide a solution how to get a solution as desired: `library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    z = as.numeric(map_lgl(y, ~eval_tidy(parse_expr(paste0("all(", .x, ")")))))
  )`